# Facebook seo url for application

Tags: facebook, url, seo

I want to create an horoscope facebook app and now I am looking for some documentation on how to rewrite the link on a facebook app like this app here?

> https://apps.facebook.com/daily-horos/**horoscope/pis**
>
> https://apps.facebook.com/daily-horos/**horoscope/tau**

etc. For each horoscope a diferent url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Example:

To make your app url like this https://apps.facebook.com/dailyhoros you have to type "dailyhoros" in the "App Namespace" box.